# Consider there is an audio file in which a person reads a sentence. How to know begining and ending time of the speech with a C, C++ or java program

Tags: audio

I am working on automatic subtitle generation project.
My approach is 
1. audio extraction ( done using ffmpeg)
2. speech to text ( can be done using sphinx 4 though not accurately)
3. subtitle generation. ( here I need help)

Consider there is an audio file in which a person reads a sentence. How to know beginning and ending time of the speech with a C, C++ or java program

we need start and end time for a  particular line in subtitle file right. So here how to retrive the time when the talking started and when ended?

any ideas?

Is it possible to do it with acoustics formula.

Comment: Is there just one sentence per audio file? Also, what format is the file in? Raw PCM?

Comment: File format is in wav I can convert to any other format.audio file may have more than one sentence. one sentence is fine too.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is very late. But i've done this using sphinx4. You don't need the start time of the audio. Sphinx4 will provide times for each recognized word. You can use that. [This](http://hv.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:241802/FULLTEXT01.pdf) research paper is helpful.